# Angular 2 toggle class on click of list items. (Higlight the item in the list)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to change the class once the item is clicked in the list , this is what i have tried to do this..

```
<div class="groups">
    <div class="group" *ngFor="#item of items | filter:queryElem.value:'title'">
        <h5>{{item.name}}</h5>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="#subItem of item.articles;#i = index">
                <span class="item toplevel" [ngClass]="{'selected': i === selectedIndex}"  href="#test" (click)="LoadArticleDetails(subItem.url,i);">{{subItem.title}}</span>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="#subarticle of subItem.children">
                           <span class="item" href="#test" [ngClass]="{'selected': i === selectedIndex}" (click)="LoadArticleDetails(subarticle.url,i);">{{subarticle.title}}</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


 export class TreeApp implements OnInit {
    selectedIndex = 0;
    LoadArticleDetails(url: string,index:any)
    {
        this.selectedIndex = index;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the current behavior and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Currently "selected" is getting added to all the items in the list. I want to highlight only that item when i click on them..

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a different index for item and sub item

```
<div class="groups">
    <div class="group" *ngFor="#item of items | filter:queryElem.value:'title'">
        <h5>{{item.name}}</h5>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.articles; let i = index">
                <span class="item toplevel" [ngClass]="{'selected': i === selectedIndex}"  href="#test" (click)="LoadArticleDetails(subItem.url,i);">{{subItem.title}}</span>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let subarticle of subItem.children let j=index">
    <span class="item" href="#test" [ngClass]="{'selected': j === selectedIndexSubItem}" (click)="LoadArticleDetailsSubItem(subarticle.url,j);">{{subarticle.title}}</span>
    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
   export class TreeApp implements OnInit {
     selectedIndex = 0;
     selectedIndexSubItem = 0;

     LoadArticleDetails(url: string,index:any) {
       this.selectedIndex = index;
     }

     LoadArticleDetailsSubItem(url: string,index:any) {
       this.selectedIndexSubItem = index;
     }

   }
```

Comment: Zochbauer Thanks for the reply , i tried with this approach its higlighting all the items in the list . I want to highlight the item only when it is clicked.. Thanks

Comment: That's unlikely. Can you reproduce in a Plunker? Your example code also shows that you are using a very old Angular2 version (`#` instead of `let`)